# MP3 Files not playing through inline player

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables

I have a page loading a datatable of mp3 files through a server side script. I am using the sound manager plugin to play the files, however they do not play inline and only open in a new window. I think this is because the inline player is initializing before the table is fully loaded, so it is not finding the mp3 files. How can I get the "listen" button to play these files inline (on the page)?

Javascript:

```
<script src="{{asset('soundmanager/js/soundmanager2-jsmin.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('soundmanager/js/inlineplayer.js')}}"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#uploads-table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "destroy": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/api/admin/tables/uploads",
        "order": [[5,'desc']],
        "columnDefs": [ { //this prevents errors if the data is null
            "targets": "_all",
            "defaultContent": ""
        } ],
        "columns": [
        // title will auto-generate th columns
            { "data": "name", "title": "Name", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "description", "title": "Description", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "file_extension", "title": "File Extension", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "mimetype", "title": "Mimetype", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "created_by", "title": "Created By", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "created_at", "title": "Created At", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "updated_at", "title": "Updated At", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "actions", "title": "Actions", "orderable": false, "searchable": false}
        ]
    });

});
</script>
```

Server side script:

```
$upload = Upload::select(array('id','name', 'description', 'file_extension', 'mimetype', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'filename', 'is_remote'));

    return Datatables::of($upload)
        ->edit_column('name', '<a href="/admin/content/uploads/{{$id}}/view">{{$name}}</a>')
        ->edit_column('created_by', function($upload) {
            return ($upload->user ? '<a href="/admin/users/'.$upload->user->id.'/view">'.$upload->user->username.'</a>' : 'Unknown');
        })
        ->edit_column('actions', function($upload) {

            if($upload->is_remote) {
                $filePath = URL::to($upload->filename);
            }
            else {
                $filePath = URL::to($upload->getFilePath());
            }

            return ('<a href="'.$filePath.'" type="'.$upload->mimetype.'" class="sm2_link" target="_blank">Listen</a>
                <a href="/admin/content/uploads/'.$upload->id.'/view" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">View</a>
                <a href="/admin/content/uploads/'.$upload->id.'/edit"  class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Edit</a>
                <a data-itemname="'.$upload->name.'" data-action="/admin/content/uploads/'.$upload->id.'/delete" data-title="Delete Upload?" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteModal" class="confirmDelete btn btn-xs btn-default">Delete</a>');
        })
        ->remove_column('id')
        ->make(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to initialize [SoundManager2 player](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/play-mp3-links/) on every table draw.

```
$('#uploads-table').dataTable( {
   drawCallback: function(settings){
      // Workaround: remove click event handler from
      // MP3 links other than the once in the table.
      inlinePlayer.removeEventHandler(document, 'click', inlinePlayer.handleClick);

      inlinePlayer.init() 
   },
   // other options 
});
```

Please note, that initializing the player is the only way to force it to rescan MP3 links. If you have other MP3 links on the page they may be initialized twice. That is why I included the line to remove click event handler before re-initializing the player.

Comment: So I spoke a little too soon, it works perfectly for the first page. However the table is paginated, so when I go to the next page it tries to play the files from the previous page over the new files. Also, the default display length is 10 uploads, but if I increase this to 25 the next 15 play, but do not pause upon click.

Comment: @Taylor23, I have updated the code, see if it works.

Comment: Works great now! Thank YOU!